# Pipenv install on Ubuntu and WSL fails

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pipenv

For some reason when I run `pipenv install` it tries to execute my Windows python.exe:

```sh
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/mnt/c/Users/<MY_USER_NAME>/AppData/Local/
Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe'
```

I am running WSL Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed Pipenv with the following commands:

```sh
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install --user pipenv
python3 -m site --user-base
```

Added `~/.local/bin` to `~/.profile` PATH, and then `source ~/.profile`

Comment: Do you also have Pipenv installed in Windows? What does `which pipenv` show if you run it from WSL?

Comment: @Chris no I don't use my Windows for development. It says `/home/pomatti/.local/bin/pipenv`

Comment: @Chris actually I had python 3.7 installed on Windows, for some reason. I uninstalled it, restarted, but the problem persists.

Comment: @Chris found it on github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```sh
pipenv install --python=/usr/bin/python3.6
```

Explanation: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3488

> The python version on Windows is higher than that on WSL, making it
>   come before the latter one..
>
> Specify python path explicitly can fix the problem:
>
> ```
> $ pipenv --python /usr/bin/python3
> ```